# Message from SendMessage should cause painting other window but it doesn't

Tags: winapi

Problem is like this:
I have two winapi application's. There is only one way communication. App1 sends message to App2. App2 should receive WM_COPYDATA with structure which has coordinates of two shapes and then it should paint those shapes.
Message is received. Data from structure is ok. Code in WM_COPYDATA case is executed which should paint window but nothing happens ( window has just solid white background)

Sending message looks like this:

```
HWND secondApp = FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, _T("lab2app2"), NULL ); 
int error = GetLastError();
if(secondApp != 0) // window found, send message
{
    // prepare data
    FiguresData figuresData;
    // Set Data About Location and dimensions of figures
    // TODO
    figuresData.square_origin_x = square_origin_x;
    figuresData.square_origin_y = square_origin_y;
    figuresData.circle_origin_x = circle_origin_x;
    figuresData.circle_origin_y = circle_origin_y;

    COPYDATASTRUCT data;

    data.dwData = FIGURESDATA;
    data.cbData = sizeof( figuresData );
    data.lpData = &figuresData;
    bool value =  SendMessage(secondApp, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)(HWND)mainWindow, (LPARAM)(LPVOID)&data);
}
```

FiguresData structure is straightforward and has only 4 ints in it.

The App2 receives messages and code for that is:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;

switch (message)
{
case WM_PAINT:

    RECT clientRectangle;
GetClientRect(hWnd, &clientRectangle);

hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    // nothing really here

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;

case WM_COPYDATA:
    {
    PCOPYDATASTRUCT pData;
    pData = (PCOPYDATASTRUCT) lParam;

    int square_origin_x = ((FiguresData *) ( pData->lpData ))->square_origin_x;
    int square_origin_y = ((FiguresData *) ( pData->lpData ))->square_origin_y;
    int circle_origin_x = ((FiguresData *) ( pData->lpData ))->circle_origin_x;
    int circle_origin_y = ((FiguresData *) ( pData->lpData ))->circle_origin_y;
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    HPEN oldPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, pen);
    HBRUSH oldBrush = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(hdc, backgroundBrush);
    COLORREF oldBackgroundColor = SetBkColor(hdc, backgroundColor);

    Rectangle(hdc, square_origin_x, square_origin_y, square_origin_x+ SQUARE_SIDE, square_origin_y + SQUARE_SIDE);
    Ellipse(hdc, circle_origin_x, circle_origin_y, circle_origin_x+ SQUARE_SIDE, circle_origin_y + SQUARE_SIDE);


    // Put everything back the way we found it
    SelectObject(hdc, oldPen);
    SetBkColor(hdc, oldBackgroundColor);

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
    }
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    break;
}

return 0;
}
```

On debugger I see that window handle is ok. Message is sent as well as received by App2 and code in the WM_COPYDATA case is executed but it has no effect. 
No shapes are drawn on the App2's window and I have no idea why. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `BeginPaint` outside of a `WM_PAINT` handler. `BeginPaint` returns a device context that allows drawing only on the invalid region of the window. Since you have not called `InvalidateRect`, the window is not yet invalid, so `BeginPaint` does not paint anything.

As a general rule, you should restrict your painting to your `WM_PAINT` handler. Have your `WM_COPYDATA` handler remember what needs to be painted, then invalidate the window and have the `WM_PAINT` handler actually paint it.